# React Navigation Drawer doubling up URI parameter

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-web

I have setup a url for the `Dashboard` page at the `NavigationContainer` level, it contains an optional `:id` param.

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['https://localhost:19006'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Dashboard: '/dashboard/:id?',
    },
  },
};
```

My Drawer looks like this:

```
export function Dashboard() {
  const route = useRoute();
  const {height} = useWindowDimensions();
  const {days, fetchPage} = useDays();
  const initialRouteName = useMemo(() => {
    if (route?.params && route?.params['id']) return route?.params['id'];
    return days.length ? days[0].id : 'loading...';
  }, [route.params, days]);

  return (
    <View style={{height: height - 65}}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        {...{
          drawerContent: props => <ContentComponent {...{...props, fetchPage}} />,
          drawerType: 'permanent',
          openByDefault: true,
          // drawerStyle: {width: '100%'},
          initialRouteName,
        }}
      >
        {!days.length ? (
          <Drawer.Screen name={initialRouteName} component={View} />
        ) : (
          days.map(day => (
            <Drawer.Screen
              key={day.id}
              name={day.id}
              initialParams={{id: day.id}}
              component={Day}
            />
          ))
        )}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The content of the drawer is being fetched. Everything works as expected to a point. You can load the page, and the default `initialRoute` is being set, and the url changes. I can click on the different drawer items. **But what fails is when I refresh.** The url `:id` duplicates, then when I refresh again, because there's no route for `/dashboard/:id/:id` it falls back to the home page.

How can I stop this doubling up, and have it so when I refresh the page it stays with the current `:id`?

Here's a gif:

[image]